# How do I add Vuforia SDK with Unity after the installation of Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have already installed Unity on my PC.now I want to use Vuforia with Unity.But in new Vuforia site they don't provide us to download their SDK for already installed Unity.How can I download it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Install the latest version of Unity, and in the Unity component
> selection section of the installer, select **Vuforia Augmented Reality
> Support**, along with either the **iOS Build Support** or **Android
> Build Support** packages.
>
> Create a Vuforia developer account from the [Vuforia registration page](https://developer.vuforia.com/user/register). This account gives you access to the tools you need to make
> AR and MR applications with Vuforia in Unity.
>
> If you have not already created a Unity ID, then do so from the [Unity registration page](https://id.unity.com/en/conversations/8c075ba1-a442-41b1-b64d-ad4fb3c56073008f?view=register&_ga=2.257431682.845003359.1549968013-1846798682.1540596226). You need a Unity ID to download any
> packages from the **Unity Asset Store**.
>
> Open Unity and create a new 3D Project (make sure the 3D option is selected next to the Add Asset Package button). Name your Project,
> then click the Create project button.
>
> To activate Vuforia in your Unity project, access the Player settings
> from **Edit > Project Settings**, then select the **Player category**,
> and select the tab for the mobile device you are building to. Under
> the **XR Settings** panel, enable the **Vuforia Augmented Reality
> Support** property.

From [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/vuforia_get_started_project_setup.html)

Comment: In new versions of Unity (I'm using 2019.2.10f1) there is no **Vuforia Augmented Reality Support** in component selection section.

You need to follow the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624126/7851379).

Comment: @Nuwan what is your idea about this matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099528/unity-crashed-when-enabling-vuforia

Answer (score 9):

Actually if you install unity 2017.2 or newer no need to add vuforia sdk. Just go to file-> build settings-> player settings ->click on vuforia augmented reality

And also in new versions of Unity (e. g. 2019.2.10f1) it is File > Build Settings > Player Settings > XR Settings > Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported checkmark

This will automatically import vuforia related assets into unity.

Comment: In new versions of Unity (e. g. 2019.2.10f1) it is File > Build Settings > Player Settings > XR Settings > Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported checkmark

Comment: This is not working for me. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099528/unity-crashed-when-enabling-vuforia

Answer (score 3):

Since 2019.3 Vuforia is not native in Unity 3D anymore:

> On Friday January 24th Unity posted an “XR Platform Updates” article.
>   Unfortunately, the original version of this article included unclear
>   information about Vuforia Engine. Vuforia Engine is still supported,
>   and will continue to be supported, in Unity. What has changed is that
>   the Vuforia Engine package will no longer be natively distributed by
>   Unity but can be easily obtained from the Unity Asset Store via our
>   Core Samples or our hosted NPM registry. You can learn more about how
>   to download the Vuforia Engine package [here](http://%20https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/vuforia-engine-package-hosting-for-unity.html).
>
> We apologize for any confusion. If you have any questions, please feel
>   free to post them on our community forums.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The Vuforia Team

We have to download an external SDK again: https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/vuforia-engine-package-hosting-for-unity.html

Comment: I installed the external SDK in Unity 2019.4 as described. But in Build Settings > Player Settings > XR Settings Vuforia does not appear in the list of Virtual Reality SDKs. It also does not appear anywhere else in the Player Settings, which I find a bit confusing.