# Unity crashed when enabling Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

My editor crashes when enabling "Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported" in XR settings. Following are the steps which I followed,

**Steps to Repro:**
1. Create a new project.
2. File > Build Settings > player settings > Player.
3. Enable "Vuforia Augmented Reality" checkbox from XR settings.

**Environment:**
Occurring on Windows 10
Unity version 2019.2.13

**Demo Video:**
[image]

What is the reason for the crashing Unity engine? I'm looking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: have you tried with a different unity version? 2019.2 is a recent version and maybe it has a bug, you can know more about bug reporting here : https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting 

Have you tried resetting the editor?

Comment: Please can you guide me to how to downgrade unity version

Comment: Nothing complicated here, just go to this link https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive and download the appropriate version. if you want less buggy then download the LTS version. You can use multiple editors, just change the installation folder name. I will suggest you to go wtih 2019.1.4f1. I am using from last six months, no major bugs.

Comment: Do I need to download all the components again which is more than 12GB? Actually I'm looking for easier solution

Comment: Nope, You can download the editor and Android Build support (because you want to build for android), everything else is not mandatory. You can download Unity Hub to easily manage the editors.

Comment: Okey Ill try with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no answer yet I would like to post what I have done to solve this matter. As @kartik Shah said this could be a bug. So I checked previous unity bug reportings and finally, I have found [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/unity-crashing-play) which is a kinda similar situation. So finally I came to conclusion this is a bug of current version 2019.2.13 and I did the following to reset unity editor into LTS(Latest Stable version) which is 2018.4.13,

**Open unity hub -> Installs -> Add -> Select LTS version -> Select the modules that you want -> Click Done**
[image]

This will download only the modules which you need to update and other modules remain as it is.

> ps: If you don't have Unity Hub you can download it from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html).